# MongoDB and Nodejs insert ID with auto increment

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to NodeJs and MongoDB, i want to insert row with auto increment primary key 'id'. also defined a function called getNextSequence on mongo server.

this is working perfect on Mongodb server

```
 > db.user.insert({   
     "id" : getNextSequence('user_id'), 
     "username" : "test", 
     "email" : "test@test.com", 
     "password" : "test123" 
 })
```

now i want to insert from NodeJs.I have tried this but not working

```
db.collection('user').insertOne({
    id : "getNextSequence('user_id')",  
    username : query.name, 
    email: query.email, 
    password: query.pass
}, function(err, result) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("row insterted ");
    callback();
});
```

Comment: Why is getNextSequence('user_id') a string ?

Comment: when i am writing it as a function .. nodejs showing error , that it is not defined as a function.... because i have define this function on mongodb server

Comment: i dnot know how to pass it

Comment: Is your function set into db.system.js ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that `getNextSequence` is a server-script function (i.e. a method you defined and saved via [`db.system.js.save`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/store-javascript-function-on-server/)), it is not callable outside of the server. One way to go is to use `eval`, which forces the server to evaluate a string as a js code, even though it is not a good practice. Here is an example:

```
db.eval('getNextSequence(\'user_id\')', function(err, result) {
  db.collection('users').insert({   
        "id" : result, 
        "username" : "test", 
        "email" : "test@test.com", 
        "password" : "test123" 
    });
});
```

---

Another way is to follow the [mongo tutorial](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/) and to implement the `getNextSequence` directly in NodeJS. The syntax is pretty much the same:

```
function getNextSequence(db, name, callback) {
    db.collection("counters").findAndModify( { _id: name }, null, { $inc: { seq: 1 } }, function(err, result){
        if(err) callback(err, result);
        callback(err, result.value.seq);
    } );
}
```

You then use it in your nodeJS code like:

```
getNextSequence(db, "user_id", function(err, result){
    if(!err){
        db.collection('users').insert({
            "_id": result,
            // ...
        });
    }
});
```

*Note*: of course, you need to have set the `counters` collection as explained in the docs.

Comment: it inserting NULL values?

Comment: I corrected the id of the sequence to match your code.

Comment: you mean `result` is null ?

Comment: I get an error. I am using same code suggested by you. TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

Answer (score 3):

**You can also use "mongoose-auto-increment".**

> The code has just 4 lines
>
> 1. var mongoose = require('mongoose');
> 2. var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment');
> 3. autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection);
> 4. userSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'user');

example :

> npm i mongoose-auto-increment

**connections.js :**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
require("dotenv").config;

const uri = process.env.MONGOURL;
mongoose.connect(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err) => {
    if (!err) { console.log('MongoDB Connection Succeeded.') }
    else { console.log('Error in DB connection : ' + err) }
});

require('../schema/userSchema');
```

**userSchema.js :**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');  // 1. require mongoose
var autoIncrement = require('mongoose-auto-increment'); // 2. require mongoose-auto-increment

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String  },  
    password: { type: String },  
    email: { type: String, unique: true, required: 'This field is required.' },    
});

autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection); // 3. initialize autoIncrement 

userSchema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, 'user'); // 4. use autoIncrement
mongoose.model('user', userSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

To accomplish this, we will create a function that will keep trying to save the document untill it will have been saved with incremented _id

```
async function retryUntilSave(db, task) {
    try {
        const index = await db.collection('tasks').find().count() + 1;
        const result = await db.collection('tasks').insertOne(Object.assign(task, { _id: index }))
    } catch (error) {
        if (error.message.includes("_id_ dup key")) {
            console.log("ID already exists!")
            console.log("Retrying...");
            
            retryUntilSave(db, task)
        } else {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
}
```

> We can use task._id: index instead of Object.assign()

finally you can test this by making some concurrent requests

```
for (let index = 0; index < 20; index++) {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        await retryUntilSave(db, { title: "Some Task" })
    }, 1000);
}
```

> This function will handle easily if two or more tasks submitted at the same time because mogod throws error when we try to insert a document with duplicate _id, then we will retry saving the document again with incremented _id and this process will run until we save the document successfully !

Comment: It's not a good solution... If I have to delete a non last item from collection then the function will fail. Imagine that I have 100 items, then I delete the first item, then I add another item... so I have two items with _id == 100. It will not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use "mongodb-autoincrement" module of node js. For example:

```
var autoIncrement = require("mongodb-autoincrement");
exports.yourMethod = function(newData, callback) {
                    autoIncrement.getNextSequence(db, your-collection-name, function (err, autoIndex) {
                        newData.id = autoIndex;
                    //save your code with this autogenerated id
                });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below package on a model schema to auto-increment your collection field.

```
mongoose-auto-increment //you can download it from npm
```

Here I am not focusing on how to connect MongoDB. I just focus on how you can integrate auto increment in your model/collection/table.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose"); //
const autoIncrement = require("mongoose-auto-increment");

const post_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    min: 3,
    max: 225,
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
});

autoIncrement.initialize(mongoose.connection);
post_schema.plugin(autoIncrement.plugin, {
  model: "post", // collection or table name in which you want to apply auto increment
  field: "_id", // field of model which you want to auto increment
  startAt: 1, // start your auto increment value from 1
  incrementBy: 1, // incremented by 1
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("post", post_schema);
```